# Qloar fine-tuning Mistral vs Llama2

Tags: pytorch, large-language-model, llama

I am fine-tuning a Mistral and a Llama2 model using the HuggingFace trainer. I set a seed using `transformers.set_seed(42)`

When fine-tuning Mistral it produces the same eval_loss every run. However, when fine-tuning Llama2 the eval_loss is different every run.

Anyone an idea where this discrapacy may arise from?